# Using postgres arrays in sliding window solution

Tags: postgresql, sliding-window

I'm having the following database problem: for each user (about 40mi) I need to perform a calculation using a 30-day sliding window, but I didn't want to scan backwards for 30 days every time. The calculation consists of counting, in that time interval, how many times the user was in class A, B or C. I thought about setting up a solution using postgres arrays, however I don't know if that would be less efficient.

The idea would be to set up a 30-position array for the users in the table, each position containing the user's class for the day. When a new day comes in, I insert the user's class into the array and remove the last day's class, preserving the size of the window. This way, I only need to look at the last partition.

Here is an example of what I was thinking.

Code to insert into the array:

```
select  
   a.user_id,
   array_prepend(a.class, b.calc_30d_arr[:30]) as count_array
from table_{last_partition} a
inner join array_table b on (a.user_id = b.user_id)
```

Code to perform the count:

```
select 
      cardinality(array_positions(calc_30d_arr, 'A')) as cnt_A,
      cardinality(array_positions(calc_30d_arr, 'B')) as cnt_B,
      cardinality(array_positions(calc_30d_arr, 'B')) as cnt_C
from array_table
```

Comment: Start by getting accurate timings for your current setup and understanding where those times come from. Then you can try your array based alternative

Comment: Rather than storing an array you can take it a step further.  Create a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) which precalculates the counts by combining your above queries. Refresh it daily. Then you can just select the counts from the materialized view assuming of course you do not need the individual 30-day values or it could be expanded to include then if needed.